# JQuery select html5 video after creation and assign EventListner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am creating an Html5 video and adding it to my webpage after it has been uploaded by the user.
I want to capture the first frame of the video and save it as an image, but I first need to wait till the video has been loaded before I run the capture script.

I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught type error: Object[object Object] has no method
>   addEventListener

I think the problem is that I am not selecting the video correctly. Because I have an unknown number of videos on the page, and because the video is wrapped in a div that has a unique ID, I am currently selecting the video as follows:

```
var video = $('#'+response).find(">:first-child");
```

This is my full code:

```
    var video = $('#'+videoID).find(">:first-child");
        console.log(video);

video.addEventListener('canplay', function(e) {
    var ratio = video.videoWidth / video.videoHeight;
    var w = 400;
    var h = 200;

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;

    context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

The console output at line 2 returns the video object, so I dont quit understand why I cannot assign the EventListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery uses `on` as opposed to `addEventListener` (which uses addEventListener where available but also supports old IE)

`$` and other jQuery functions return a jQuery object which is like a collection of elements.

Comment: I feel so stupid that I missed this :( thats what working on a project for 10 hours will do to u! thanks!